# Styling every row but the first in HTML definition list

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

What's the simplest selector for styling every row (by row I mean every `dd`-`dt` pair, which in my mind seem to appear on the same line) of the definition list, but the first? I need to set the top margin.

```
<dl>
  <dt>...</dt>
  <dd>...</dd>

  <dt>...</dt>
  <dd>...</dd>

  <dt>...</dt>
  <dd>...</dd>

  (...)
</dl>
```

My aim is below. Is there a simpler way to write it?

```
dl > dt:not(:first-of-type),
dl > dd:not(:first-of-type) {
    margin: 1mm 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: just use dt+dt or dt ~ dt if there's dd in between , first one will not apply the style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from my comment:

> just use `dt+dt` or `dt ~ dt` if there's `dd` in between , first one will not apply the style

To also style `dd` behind , repeat the selector and use it as well for dd : `dt ~dt ~dd`

```css
dt ~dt {
  color: red;
}
dt ~dt ~dd {
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt> first</dt>
  <dd>in between</dd>
  <dt>not first</dt>
  <dd>in between</dd>
  <dt> not first</dt>
  <dd>in between</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: That seems to be a simple neat solution. Thank you!

Comment: But I guess to fully answer my question you should also add `dd ~ dd` selector, because styling `dt` elements only won't style the full row.

Comment: @Robert if you want also to style dd after second dt, you need : dt ~dt ~dd also ;)

Comment: I said I want to style every **row** but the first - so every `dd` and `dt` excluding the first ones on the list.

Comment: @ then just style dd ??

Comment: I see the misunderstaning now. *row* for me meant `dd`-`dt` pair, while they in general don't have to be in the same row. Sorry for not clarifying that.

Comment: Sure, it's easy to fix. I just want to accept your answer, but can't do that until it fully/correctly answers the question.

Comment: @Robert I'm still lost (my average understanding of english) where does my update is missing your requirement ?

Comment: Isn't `dt ~dt ~dd` a little overkill? Wouldn't `dd ~ dd` accomplish the same?

Comment: @Robert it would if you are sure that you have a single dd after the first dt :)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you can have multiple `dd`s for a single `dt`. Then I guess your solution is better (more general).

Comment: @Robert it could if you would build a dictionnary from a dl list ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
dl > dt:nth-of-type(n + 2) { ... }
dl > dd:nth-of-type(n + 2) { ... }
```

breakdown:

```
0 + 2 = 2nd instance
1 + 2 = 3rd instance
2 + 2 = 4th instance
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: That one I didn't know about and it looks pretty flexible. Thanks.